# diff_drive_controller ignores acceleration limits

Tags: ros, diff-drive-controller

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello community,

I have a real 2-wheeled robot and use diff_drive_controller. I'm able to drive around using teleop. It seems to work so far.
But I'm curious about max_jerk and max_acceleration setting as they are not used for some reason. I tried different values and now even very low values but it doesn't make any difference.

From my understanding, diff_drive_controller subscribes to /cmd_vel and translate this to separate commands for each joint(wheel).

So when the current linear velocity is 0m/s and I publish a message to /cmd_vel telling to set linear velocity to 1m/s, robot instantly drives whith this speed. If I switch between forward/backward with max velocity, it jumps around.

My assumption is that diff_drive_controller takes care of acceleration limits resulting in a smooth movement of robot. I tried different max_velocity values just for check and these are used by diff_drive_controller

Any ideas of what is wrong here?

```
    hoverboard_joint_publisher:
  type: "joint_state_controller/JointStateController"
  publish_rate: 50
  left_wheel  : 'left_wheel'
  right_wheel : 'right_wheel'

hoverboard_velocity_controller:
  type        : "diff_drive_controller/DiffDriveController"
  left_wheel  : 'left_wheel'
  right_wheel : 'right_wheel'
  publish_rate: 50.0               # default: 50
  pose_covariance_diagonal : [0.001, 0.001, 1000000.0, 1000000.0, 1000000.0, 1000.0]
  twist_covariance_diagonal: [0.001, 0.001, 1000000.0, 1000000.0, 1000000.0, 1000.0]

  # Wheel separation and diameter. These are both optional.
  # diff_drive_controller will attempt to read either one or both from the
  # URDF if not specified as a parameter
  wheel_separation : 0.32
  wheel_radius : 0.0825

  # Wheel separation and radius multipliers
  wheel_separation_multiplier: 1.0 # default: 1.0
  wheel_radius_multiplier    : 1.0 # default: 1.0

  # Velocity commands timeout [s], default 0.5
  cmd_vel_timeout: 0.5

  # Base frame_id
  base_frame_id: base_footprint #default: base_link
  allow_multiple_cmd_vel_publishers: true
  odom_frame_id: '/raw_odom'
  enable_odom_tf: false

  # Velocity and acceleration limits
  # Whenever a min_* is unspecified, default to -max_*
  linear:
    x:
      has_velocity_limits    : true
      max_velocity           : 0.5  # m/s
      has_acceleration_limits: true
      max_acceleration       : 0.01  # m/s^2
      has_jerk_limits        : true
      max_jerk               : 0.001  # m/s^3
  angular:
    z:
      has_velocity_limits    : true # was true
      max_velocity           : 6.28  # rad/s
      has_acceleration_limits: true # was true
      max_acceleration       : 1.04  # rad/s^2
      has_jerk_limits        : true
      max_jerk               : 3.14  # rad/s^3
```

This is how launch file looks like

```
<launch>
    <rosparam file="$(find hoverboard_driver)/config/hardware.yaml" command="load"/>
    <rosparam file="$(find hoverboard_driver)/config/controllers.yaml" command="load"/>

      <!-- PS4 joypad -->
  <remap from="/cmd_vel" to="/hoverboard_velocity_controller/cmd_vel"/>    
  <include file="$(find ds4_driver)/launch/ds4_twist.launch">
    <arg name="dof" value="2"/>
    <!--<arg name="topic" value="joy_vel"/> -->
    
  </include>


    <node name="hoverboard_driver" pkg="hoverboard_driver" type="hoverboard_driver" output="screen"/>
    <node name="controller_spawner" pkg="controller_manager" type="spawner" respawn="false" output="screen" ns="/"
        args="hoverboard_joint_publisher hoverboard_velocity_controller" />
</launch>
```

rostopic list:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ rostopic list
/hoverboard/battery_voltage
/hoverboard/left_wheel/cmd
/hoverboard/left_wheel/position
/hoverboard/left_wheel/velocity
/hoverboard/right_wheel/cmd
/hoverboard/right_wheel/position
/hoverboard/right_wheel/velocity
/hoverboard/temperature
/hoverboard_velocity_controller/cmd_vel
/hoverboard_velocity_controller/odom
/hoverboard_velocity_controller/parameter_descriptions
/hoverboard_velocity_controller/parameter_updates
/joint_states
/pid/left/parameter_descriptions
/pid/left/parameter_updates
/pid/right/parameter_descriptions
/pid/right/parameter_updates
/rosout
/rosout_agg
/tf
```

Here the output of /joint_state. At beginning, robots velocity is set to 0m/s and then instantly to 1m/s. It accelerates way faster as it should do from my opinion. Max velocity has been set to 0.5m/s which is close to 6rad/s as radius of wheel is 0.0825

```
header:
  seq: 38106
  stamp:
    secs: 1625854242
    nsecs: 451236534
  frame_id: ''
name:
  - left_wheel
  - right_wheel
position: [316.2536604613725, 310.38935417467155]
velocity: [0.0, 0.0]
effort: [0.0, 0.0]
---
header:
  seq: 38107
  stamp:
    secs: 1625854242
    nsecs: 471224839
  frame_id: ''
name:
  - left_wheel
  - right_wheel
position: [316.32347363145226, 310.45916734475134]
velocity: [0.5236, 0.62832]
effort: [0.0, 0.0]
---
header:
  seq: 38108
  stamp:
    secs: 1625854242
    nsecs: 491229967
  frame_id: ''
name:
  - left_wheel
  - right_wheel
position: [316.39328680153204, 310.5289805148311]
velocity: [4.08408, 3.76992]
effort: [0.0, 0.0]
---
header:
  seq: 38109
  stamp:
    secs: 1625854242
    nsecs: 511226762
  frame_id: ''
name:
  - left_wheel
  - right_wheel
position: [316.4630999716118, 310.5987936849109]
velocity: [3.6651999999999996, 4.1888]
effort: [0.0, 0.0]
---
header:
  seq: 38110
  stamp:
    secs: 1625854242
    nsecs: 521235628
  frame_id: ''
name:
  - left_wheel
  - right_wheel
position: [316.5329131416916, 310.5987936849109]
velocity: [1.4660799999999998, 4.1888]
effort: [0.0, 0.0]
---
header:
  seq: 38111
  stamp:
    secs: 1625854242
    nsecs: 541368724
  frame_id: ''
name:
  - left_wheel
  - right_wheel
position: [316.60272631177133, 310.6686068549907]
velocity: [4.50296, 3.6651999999999996]
effort: [0.0, 0.0]
---
header:
  seq: 38112
  stamp:
    secs: 1625854242
    nsecs: 571235323
  frame_id: ''
name:
  - left_wheel
  - right_wheel
position: [316.7423526519309, 310.8082331951502]
velocity: [4.50296, 4.29352]
effort: [0.0, 0.0]
---
header:
  seq: 38113
  stamp:
    secs: 1625854242
    nsecs: 591233940
  frame_id: ''
name:
  - left_wheel
  - right_wheel
position: [316.8121658220107, 310.87804636523]
velocity: [5.02656, 3.87464]
effort: [0.0, 0.0]
---
header:
  seq: 38114
  stamp:
    secs: 1625854242
    nsecs: 601232806
  frame_id: ''
name:
  - left_wheel
  - right_wheel
position: [316.88197899209047, 310.94785953530976]
velocity: [4.1888, 4.9218399999999995]
effort: [0.0, 0.0]
---
header:
  seq: 38115
  stamp:
    secs: 1625854242
    nsecs: 631224613
  frame_id: ''
name:
  - left_wheel
  - right_wheel
position: [317.09141850232976, 311.0874858754693]
velocity: [4.7124, 4.7124]
effort: [0.0, 0.0]
---
header:
  seq: 38116
  stamp:
    secs: 1625854242
    nsecs: 641237749
  frame_id: ''
name:
  - left_wheel
  - right_wheel
position: [317.09141850232976, 311.0874858754693]
velocity: [4.7124, 4.7124]
effort: [0.0, 0.0]
---
header:
  seq: 38117
  stamp:
    secs: 1625854242
    nsecs: 671225077
  frame_id: ''
name:
  - left_wheel
  - right_wheel
position: [317.2310448424893, 311.2969253857086]
velocity: [5.131279999999999, 5.02656]
effort: [0.0, 0.0]
---
header:
  seq: 38118
  stamp:
    secs: 1625854242
    nsecs: 691222496
  frame_id: ''
name:
  - left_wheel
  - right_wheel
position: [317.3008580125691, 311.3667385557884]
velocity: [5.131279999999999, 5.236]
effort: [0.0, 0.0]
---
header:
  seq: 38119
  stamp:
    secs: 1625854242
    nsecs: 701232664
  frame_id: ''
name:
  - left_wheel
  - right_wheel
position: [317.3706711826489, 311.4365517258682]
velocity: [5.236, 5.44544]
effort: [0.0, 0.0]
---
header:
  seq: 38120
  stamp:
    secs: 1625854242
    nsecs: 731246137
  frame_id: ''
name:
  - left_wheel
  - right_wheel
position: [317.5102975228084, 311.5761780660277]
velocity: [5.340719999999999, 5.55016]
effort: [0.0, 0.0]
---
header:
  seq: 38121
  stamp:
    secs: 1625854242
    nsecs: 751225536
  frame_id: ''
name:
  - left_wheel
  - right_wheel
position: [317.64992386296797, 311.71580440618726]
velocity: [6.07376, 5.44544]
effort: [0.0, 0.0]
---
header:
  seq: 38122
  stamp:
    secs: 1625854242
    nsecs: 771221758
  frame_id: ''
name:
  - left_wheel
  - right_wheel
position: [317.78955020312753, 311.8554307463468]
velocity: [5.44544, 5.6548799999999995]
effort: [0.0, 0.0]
---
header:
  seq: 38123
  stamp:
    secs: 1625854242
    nsecs: 791225011
  frame_id: ''
name:
  - left_wheel
  - right_wheel
position: [317.8593633732073, 311.92524391642655]
velocity: [5.6548799999999995, 5.55016]
effort: [0.0, 0.0]
---
header:
  seq: 38124
  stamp:
    secs: 1625854242
    nsecs: 811237274
  frame_id: ''
name:
  - left_wheel
  - right_wheel
position: [317.9989897133668, 312.0648702565861]
velocity: [5.55016, 5.6548799999999995]
effort: [0.0, 0.0]
---
header:
  seq: 38125
  stamp:
    secs: 1625854242
    nsecs: 831210683
  frame_id: ''
name:
  - left_wheel
  - right_wheel
position: [318.1386160535264, 312.2044965967457]
velocity: [5.55016, 5.864319999999999]
effort: [0.0, 0.0]
---
header:
  seq: 38126
  stamp:
    secs: 1625854242
    nsecs: 841238403
  frame_id: ''
name:
  - left_wheel
  - right_wheel
position: [318.2084292236062, 312.27430976682547]
velocity: [5.6548799999999995, 5.864319999999999]
effort: [0.0, 0.0]
---
header:
  seq: 38127
  stamp:
    secs: 1625854242
    nsecs: 871228543
  frame_id: ''
name:
  - left_wheel
  - right_wheel
position: [318.34805556376574, 312.413936106985]
velocity: [5.7596, 5.96904]
effort: [0.0, 0.0]
---
header:
  seq: 38128
  stamp:
    secs: 1625854242
    nsecs: 891231848
  frame_id: ''
name:
  - left_wheel
  - right_wheel
position: [318.48768190392525, 312.55356244714454]
velocity: [5.7596, 5.7596]
effort: [0.0, 0.0]
---
header:
  seq: 38129
  stamp:
    secs: 1625854242
    nsecs: 901243526
  frame_id: ''
name:
  - left_wheel
  - right_wheel
position: [318.55749507400503, 312.6233756172243]
velocity: [5.7596, 5.864319999999999]
effort: [0.0, 0.0]
---
header:
  seq: 38130
  stamp:
    secs: 1625854242
    nsecs: 931226687
  frame_id: ''
name:
  - left_wheel
  - right_wheel
position: [318.6971214141646, 312.76300195738384]
velocity: [5.7596, 5.7596]
effort: [0.0, 0.0]
---
header:
  seq: 38131
  stamp:
    secs: 1625854242
    nsecs: 951222700
  frame_id: ''
name:
  - left_wheel
  - right_wheel
position: [318.8367477543241, 312.9026282975434]
velocity: [5.236, 6.07376]
effort: [0.0, 0.0]
---
header:
  seq: 38132
  stamp:
    secs: 1625854242
    nsecs: 971380119
  frame_id: ''
name:
  - left_wheel
  - right_wheel
position: [318.9763740944837, 313.04225463770297]
velocity: [6.07376, 5.96904]
effort: [0.0, 0.0]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/382088/diff_drive_controller-ignores-acceleration-limits/) by [PaddyCube](https://answers.ros.org/users/40932/paddycube/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2021-07-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-09**:
The diff_drive_controller source files do contain code to limit the acceleration. What makes you think it is not being used when you are using the navigation stack? Is this simulation or a real robot? If you monitor the JointState, does that jump too?

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-09**:
Please edit your question and append the output from `rosnode list`.

**Comment by [PaddyCube](https://answers.ros.org/users/40932/paddycube/) on 2021-07-09**:
This is a real robot. If I send cmd_vel with linear velocity of 1m/s, robot immediately starts to run with this speed. I just publish this message either by console or joystick. Does acceleration limit only gets respected when used navigation stack? Right now, my robot is just some kind of RC car as you see.

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-09**:
Anything published to cmd_vel should have accel limits applied. You are correct that joint velocity should not jump up like that in a couple hundred milliseconds. What are `/pid/left` and `/pid/right`? How have you configured them?

**Comment by [PaddyCube](https://answers.ros.org/users/40932/paddycube/) on 2021-07-11**:
I found a bug inside my main loop.

```
    while (ros::ok()) {
    const ros::Time time = ros::Time::now();
    const ros::Duration period = time - prev_time;

    hoverboard.read();
    cm.update(time, period);
    hoverboard.write(time, period);

    rate.sleep();
}
```

prev_time was only set outside the loop but never inside the loop. I added `prev_time = time` right before rate.sleep. It works now if I set acceleration very low (0.1 m/s²) but if I set it higher, it still accelerates slow and starts to oscilate afterwards by running forward, backward, forward, backward even if there is no /cmd_vel message is applied anymore

**Comment by [PaddyCube](https://answers.ros.org/users/40932/paddycube/) on 2021-07-11**:
This is my currend PID setting. The entire code has been developed by other people and I still try to understand how it works.

```
from dynamic_reconfigure.parameter_generator_catkin import *
gen = ParameterGenerator()
#        Name            Type      Level  Description                           Default   Min    Max
gen.add( "f" ,           double_t, 1,     "Feed forward gain.",                 10.0,     -100,  100)
gen.add( "p" ,           double_t, 1,     "Proportional gain.",                 10.0,     -100,  100)
gen.add( "i" ,           double_t, 1,     "Integral gain.",                     0.1,      -100,  100)
gen.add( "d" ,           double_t, 1,     "Derivative gain.",                   1.0,      -100,  100)
gen.add( "i_clamp_min" , double_t, 1,     "Min bounds for the integral windup", -10.0,    -100,    0)
gen.add( "i_clamp_max" , double_t, 1,     "Max bounds for the integral windup", 10.0,     0,     100)
gen.add( "antiwindup" ,  bool_t,   1,     "Antiwindup.",
```

**Comment by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) on 2021-07-12**:
Good work figuring out that bug. That oscillation happens because the PID controller is not configured properly, so the velocity output to the motor is unstable. If it were me, as a starting point for the PID, I would set p=0.1, i=0, d=0. I have no way to determine what `f` should be; whoever did this hardware interface layer should have provided the proper value, which I suspect is based on what the motor wants to see at its input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a `hardware_interface` layer that sits between the `diff_drive_controller` and the motors. This layer has to work properly, and the PID controllers be tuned properly, for the robot to move smoothly and at the requested velocity. As far as I can tell from our discussion, the `diff_drive_controller` is functioning as expected.

---

Originally posted by [Mike Scheutzow](https://answers.ros.org/users/75154/mike-scheutzow/) with karma: 4903 on 2021-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0